# XML Parsing Error: not well-formed ? anyone can

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest, linq-to-xml

This is my first time creating a xml document but I am having problems with one line not working. can anyone tell me what I have done wrong.

http://www.ncerttext.in/flipkart.xml
error is

7:  107 The entity "wgtid" was referenced, but not declared.

how should i do that.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You could try running your XML file through [www.xmlvalidation.com](http://www.xmlvalidation.com) and see if it gives you any clues.

Comment: yes. i know what you are doing wrong and suggest reading some basic xml tutorials. The magix word is `&amp;`

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by @Marco Forberg, the problematic character in your XML is `"&"`. Simply change `&` to `&amp;`.

By the way: Modern browsers tell you something about XML files even if they are malformed. For example, if you open your file with a recent version of Firefox, hit `Ctrl+U` and hover over the red character, it informs you that `&` is not allowed and should most probably be changed to `&amp;`.