# XML not declared: anyone can

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest, linq-to-xml

This is my first time creating a xml document but I am having problems with one line not working. can anyone tell me what I have done wrong.

http://www.ncerttext.in/flipkart.xml

error is,

7: 107 The entity "wgtid" was referenced, but not declared.

how should i do that.

Comment: Duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20047789/xml-parsing-error-not-well-formed-anyone-can

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you would need to escape the ampersand ("&") within the URL in line 7 by replacing it by the sequence "&amp;".

Comment: Please add code formatting to the `"&amp"` - otherwise it is automatically turned into "&" again.