# xml file bounce with an error

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest

I want this line to be in my xml file,

but when it is placed it returns with an error

How can I represent this url in a way that the xml parser will allow?

the line is,

search-all?**affid**=pvgmarketi&**wgtid**=FK-AF-SB">

the problem is that "=" sign after **wgtid** is not well formed by the xml file

but there is no problem with the "=" sign after **affid**

help

Comment: you cant use '&' in xml, use &amp; instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is now a double duplicate of [XML Parsing Error: not well-formed ? anyone can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20047789/xml-parsing-error-not-well-formed-anyone-can) already. Please stop posting the same question over again.

Just read the explanations that are given to you. But for the record, here is it again:
Your XML parser (e.g. browser) thinks that `&wgtid` is an **entity**, because entities start with a "&" character in XML.

So, "&" is not allowed if you mean "&". You have to write it as `&amp;` if you literally mean "&" as a character.

Comment: Please consider accepting this as an answer if it helped you solve your problem (mark the tick on the left).